# jQuery: Why can't my script remove the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery won't remove the class after scrolling

This is my script:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#white").offset().top -70) {
        $('.burger-menu').addClass('white');
    } else {
        $('.burger-menu').removeClass('white');
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#color-main").offset().top -70) {
        $('.burger-menu').addClass('color-main');
    } else {
        $('.burger-menu').removeClass('color-main');
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#yellow").offset().top -70) {
        $('.burger-menu').addClass('yellow');
    } else {
        $('.burger-menu').removeClass('yellow');
    }
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<section class="home-page" id="white">Blablabla</section>
<section class="wrap" id="color-main">Blablabla</section>
<section class="wrap" id="yellow">Blablabla</section>
```

but my `<div>`

```
<div class="burger-menu white color-main yellow">
```

still has the classes "white" and "color-main", which should be removed. :(

I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/antho-fsy/pen/ZQqoGZ) for you to see it.

Comment: That means your condition fails, and the numbers don't add up. Log the numbers and see what you get when scrolling.

Comment: When I try the code it works fine. I put a line 70px down the page, and the burger menu is fixed at the top right showing the active classes. When the sections reach the line the classes light up in the burger menu: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/yka8nzt4/

Comment: @Guffa when i scroll at the bottom, i have this :<div class="burger-menu white color-main yellow"> but i want <div class="burger-menu yellow">

Comment: Aha, then you should remove the classes above. I posted code below.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 fixes I would recommed you try:

1. Don't do multiple `.scroll(function(){...})` calls, they overwrite each other.
2. Use `$("body").scroll(function(){...})`, because that's the element you (usally) scroll in

Comment: ow, okay, I'm newbie in js and i dont know how can i fix my error but thanks for the answer

Comment: `.scroll()` installs an event handler.  You can call it as many times as you want to create multiple event handlers.  There is no overwriting here.

Comment: No, events are not overwritten in jQuery, it supports multiple events. When I try the code the `$(window).scroll()` methods works fine. Does that differ between browsers? Do you have any example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: Idk but I think you even have some CSS errors, but please only use a singe `.scroll`.

Comment: @jfriend00 If that's not the case I'm sorry, but I'm pretty sure if you do like `btn.onclick = ...` and then again it will overwrite it, right?

Comment: @timmyRS - Yes `btn.onclick = function() {...}` will overwrite, but not jQuery's event handlers like `.scroll()` or `.click()` or `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

The below example uses only the IF statement and deletes the other classes. Try this and see if you get the result you desire. Instead of relying on an ELSE that could be broken by another scroll function else statement we simply remove all classes and only add the class you want.

Example:

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#white").offset().top - 70) {
           $('.burger-menu').removeClass("color-main").removeClass("yellow").addClass('white');
       }
   });
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#color-main").offset().top - 70) {
           $('.burger-menu').removeClass("white").removeClass("yellow").addClass('color-main');
       } 
   });
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#yellow").offset().top - 70) {
           $('.burger-menu').removeClass("color-main").removeClass("white").addClass('yellow');
       } 
   });
```

Comment: yes it s work but i have 12 function, we cant reduce this?

Comment: Im sure we can, post the full code and html on jsfiddle and send me the link, ill see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with those who suggest putting them all in a single `.scroll()` function. This worked for me:

```
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#white").offset().top - 70) {
      $('.burger-menu').addClass('white');
    } else {
      $('.burger-menu').removeClass('white');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#color-main").offset().top - 70) {
      $('.burger-menu').addClass('color-main');
    } else {
      $('.burger-menu').removeClass('color-main');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#yellow").offset().top - 70) {
      $('.burger-menu').addClass('yellow');
    } else {
      $('.burger-menu').removeClass('yellow');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have only one class active at a time, use `removeClass` to remove the others. You can use a single `scroll` event handler, and rearrange the code to look for the last section first, that makes the code simpler:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var top = $(window).scrollTop() + 70;

  if (top >= $("#yellow").offset().top) {
    $('.burger-menu').removeClass('white color-main').addClass('yellow');
  } else if(top >= $("#color-main").offset().top) {
    $('.burger-menu').removeClass('white yellow').addClass('color-main');
  } else if (top >= $("#white").offset().top) {
    $('.burger-menu').removeClass('color-main yellow').addClass('white');
  } else {
    $('.burger-menu').removeClass('white color-main yellow');
  }

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/yka8nzt4/1/

Another way would be to determine the status for each class:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var top = $(window).scrollTop() + 70;
  var white = top >= $("#white").offset().top;
  var main = top >= $("#color-main").offset().top;
  var yellow = top >= $("#yellow").offset().top;

  $('.burger-menu')
    .toggleClass('white', white && !main)
    .toggleClass('color-main', main && !yellow)
    .toggleClass('yellow', yellow);

});
```